# Positioning and panning/zooming Flot chart in Android WebView

Tags: android, css, cordova, flot

I'm working on an Android project where I have a [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) chart, running in [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/). Here is how my HTML page is set up, with layout handled by [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/):

- Flot "placeholder" div
- A div containing custom buttons that enable manipulation of the chart
- A form

Here are the issues I have:

- **How do I dynamically size the Flot chart to fit the space available on the screen?** Right now, I have the chart set to a static size, but I'd prefer to be able to determine the screen's size (in landspace mode), and set the chart width to that.
- **How do I enable panning and zoom of the chart?** My app supports that functionality when it is run in a standard desktop browser - there, I pan by clicking and dragging the chart, and I zoom by rotating my mouse wheel over the chart. When I try those things in the Android emulator, either the entire app is panned (not just the chart), or nothing happens (the mouse wheel doesn't do anything in the emulator). How can I pan and zoom just the chart itself, not the entire app?

Answer (score 4):

1)
Simply create a container div with style width:100%
You can redraw the graph when orientation changes by adding a PhoneGap eventlistener:

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange', function(event) {
    $.plot($(graphId), .....
});
```

Instead of reinitializing the graph can resize by calling:

```
plot.resize();
plot.setupGrid();
plot.draw();
```

This may also perform slightly better.

If you experience that the graph is not cleared correctly before redraw, you can force a clear using:

```
$(graphId).text('');
```

I've experienced problems when the graph is inside a div with data-role=content, just remove the data-role.